# Reset the Html Form after form submission and prevent user to come back and see the submitted data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, http

On an HTML page when I make a HTTP POST submission, it redirects to another page as a result.

On the redirected page, user can come back to form page and see the submitted values again by hitting the back button of the browser. This is not much of a problem but think about this scenario:

> A user goes to a public internet cafe and buy something with a credit
>   card. Then leaves the Internet Cafe and forgot to close the browser.
>   The next user comes to that desk and hit back button and boom!

An ignorant user about internet can blame the company for that action.

What I would like to do is to reset the HTML form after the form submission and prevent user to come back and see the submitted data.

I can use a simple JavaScript code to do that. For example, something like below:

```
<script>
    $("input[type='text']").val(null);
</script>
```

But, JavaScript can be disabled.

I am developing this app on ASP.NET MVC but I don't think that there is any way to solve this issue on server side.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you clear out the form fields, their values will be delivered as auto-complete entries. You can stop this by switching off auto-completion:

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...>
```

Which I know is supported by Internet Explorer and Firefox for HTML4 and is in the HTML5 specification.

Comment: Whoa! I've missed knowing this for so long! :) Thnx!

Comment: Oh dear. I do hope this knowledge doesn't spread too quickly. I would hate to have to start entering my personal details character by character again...

Comment: @MarjanVenema - developers should know about these attributes. We are all grown up enough to decide when it is and isn't appropriate to use them. For example, I would't want autocomplete on the field I use to enter my Facebook status, but I would want it on a field asking for my name.

Comment: @Sohnee: I agree with you, it's just that I have seen this kind of knowledge misused a little too much. Think: disabling the back button, preventing right clicks on links. There are always cases where it would be appropriate but unfortunately there are also many cases where what's possible is used for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 4):

If the scenario is as in your example, my advice is to **never process credit card information by yourself**. There are various payment services (paypal and others) that have gadgets and apis that handle the data securely.

Also, if you are worried about dealing with sensitive user data, first of all you should always use SSL (https). Second, you can tell the browser to forget the original form data using the OutputCacheAttribute on your action method:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public ActionResult SomeAction() { }
```

Don't use javascript for this.

Comment: I need to process Credit Card data myself. I have no option there. But, the cache control tip is useful. I think the same for JavaScript.

Comment: `no-cache` is probably your best option.

Comment: Are you really sure that you can guarantee the safety of your users' credit card information? It is not an easy task! And I would never, ever, do business with a web site that handles my credit card information by itself...

Comment: Well, `Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store` is no use on chrome for this.

Comment: Well, let me tell you the situation: we are working with a Turkish bank here and they have a REST service which accepts requests. I do not store credit card info on my server, I am just passing to the bank and get the authentication I am not sure what you mean by "**I would never, ever, do business with a web site that handles my credit card information by itself...**". Do I have another choice here?

Comment: Not if you are set on working with that bank. I only ever let the major payment service providers handle my credit card info, like Google Checkout or PayPal. Luckily for you, most internet users are not that aware of the risks involved. How do you guarantee the safety of the credit card information?

Comment: Well, you are right at some point. This is what I do: 1-) I never store CC info anywhere in my servers. 2-) I process under SSL. 3-) I am thinking about **3D secure** but not sure how it works internationally. Anyway, I just get the request, package it up and send it to the bank and get the response back as XML. Anything else that I need to do here?